# How do I bind a Model Object while using resource controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1

What I'm looking for is something like this

```
public function store(Help $help)
{
    $help->save();

    return response
}
```

I have added the model class is Routes.php file like this

```
Route::model('help', 'App\Help');
Route::resource('api/help', 'HelpController');
```

And this is my Help.php file

```
class Help extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $table = 'help';

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = array('name','description','deleted_at','created_at', 'updated_at');

}
```

Binding is happening to an extent, i.e, there is a new row in the table but the attributes "name" and "description" are empty.

Comment: You aren't setting them? `$help->name = 'XXX';` etc

Comment: Do I need to? That is what I'm trying to achieve. Without explicitly setting them, I want them to be mapped. Is that possible?

Comment: HOW should the app know what the values are, when you are not setting them..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the route model binding concept...

I think, what you really want, is something like that:

```
public function store(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $help = new Help($request->all());
    $help->save();

    return back()->with('success', true);
}
```

Route Model Binding is more likely to be used for example on the update method, as you have an existing instance of your model, you can work with.

For example:

```
public function update(Illuminate\Http\Request $request , Help $help) {
    // help exists and the correct model instance is automatically resolved through route model binding...
    $help->fill( $request->all() );
    $help->save();

    return redirect()->back()->with( 'updated', true );
}
```

You can run the command

```
php artisan route:list
```

To check where Route Model Binding can be used. The variables you see in {} 
like {help}

Comment: Thanks. What I assumed was, if my request JSON was something like { "name":"Help name", "description":"Help description"}, it could automatically map the attributes.